# About submit an update of my iOS app through Application Loader to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I am submitting a new update to my existing app in Apple Store.

I archived my iOS project to ipa file. Then, I opened Application Loader in xcode from Xcode--> Open Developer Tool --> Application Loader.

Then, I uploaded my ipa file to **iTunes Connect** through the Application loader.

Then, I logged in to my iTunes Connect, I see this:

[image]

As you see, on the left hand side, there is "All Builds", I can find my uploaded build there. Under "All Builds", there is "App Store Versions".

**My question** is, should I just wait until apple verify my app then my uploaded build will be moved to "App Store Versions"? Or, should I still do something after uploading my IPA file through Xcode's Application Loader tool? I am asking it because I see some builds in the "All Builds" list doesn't have a "App Store Status":
[image]

e.g. the above one has been uploaded to iTune Connect in March, until now, there is no "App Store Status", it sounds like Apple never verify it. I don't want my update end up with never been verified by Apple. That's why I ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit any number of builds for each app version. They only need to have to different build number. Whenever you want to create a new version you have to pick one build from the ones available (the ones with the same version).

You can upload new builds from Xcode or Application Loader. It's the same (I usually use the last one since it seems to work better, at least for me).

For example: you want to create an update of your app, let's call it v1.0.1. You have to create this new version and give it the name 1.0.1 in iTunesConnect. Once you have done that, you have to upload with Xcode or Application Loader at least one build that matches the version 1.0.1. Since build numbers need to be bigger than the previous ones, let's suppose that you upload one build with the build number 20170925 (todays date yyyyMMdd). You will be able to pick this build in the app update section in order to set up the update and send it to be reviewed. Imagine that you just notice that in the uploaded build something fails. Well, this is not the end of the world. You just need to create a new build with the same version name (1.0.1) and different build number (bigger, for example 20170926). Once the new build is processed you will be able to select it in the 1.0.1 update screen.

Summarizing, many builds can have the same version and only one of them will be released.

Comment: So, what's next should I do after I uploaded the iPA to iTunesConnect through Application Loader now in order to have my submission to release out as an update of my existing app?

Comment: You have to enter inside your app record in iTunesConnect and pick (+ Version or platform). Fill the version name and all the data required for the update submision (picking the build, fill the new features section...). Once you have done that you have to press the Save button and then the "Submit for Review" button. More instructions in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html